# How do I mark a Salesforce Trailmix task as complete?

Tags: trailhead, pardot

**Prepare for your Pardot Specialist Credential**
Trailmix by Salesforce Trailhead
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/users/strailhead/trailmixes/prepare-for-your-pardot-specialist-credential

I did click the `Follow` button in the upper right on the Trailmix page.
I did clear cache and reload after following the Trailmix.

The `Link` steps have a `Mark as Complete` button.
The `Task` steps have no `Mark as Complete` button, instructions, or interactive features.

What are we supposed to do for Tasks?

[image: Pardot Specialist Credential Trailmix screenshot]

... and nothing happens to the `Task` after I complete the previous steps.

[image: Pardot Specialist Credential Trailmix screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Task is like a milestone without completion button. The trailmix will be completed once you mark all links and complete all modules.